# Маска ввода номера телефона TextBox WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox, mask

Хотелось бы сделать маску ввода в textbox, номера телефона, формат: +7(999)999-99-99.

У меня есть приложение на WPF .NET 5
[image: Главное окно]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="GIBDD_TESTS.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local = "clr-namespace:GIBDD_TESTS"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="425" Width="587">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name = "BtnDBConnect" Content="Connect" Margin="434,28,53,0" Click="BtnDBConnect_Click" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name = "LbDBFileName" Content="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="157,25,175,0" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Red" FontWeight="Regular"/>
        <Label x:Name = "LbDB" Content="Data base:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,25,0,0" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TbSername" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="51,62,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Surname" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TbName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="176,62,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TbPatronymic" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="301,62,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Patronymic" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TbPassportNumber" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="426,62,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Passport Number" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TbRegistrationAddress" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="236,85,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Registration Address" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310" Height="60"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TbResidentialAddress" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="236,150,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Residential Address" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310" Height="60"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TbPlaceOfWork" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="51,215,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Place of work" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TbPost" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="301,215,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Post" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TbPhoneNumber" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="51,238,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Phone Number" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="243"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TbEmailAddress" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="301,238,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Email" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245"/>
        <Image x:Name="ImPhoto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="118" Margin="51,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89"/>
        <Button x:Name="BtnPhotoSet" Content="Photo set" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="157,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" Click="BtnPhotoSet_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="BtnPhotoClear" Content="Photo Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="157,130,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="BtnPhotoClear_Click"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TbCommens" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="51,261,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Commens" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="495" Height="100"/>
        <Button x:Name="BtnWriteInDB" Content="Write" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="486,366,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" Click="BtnWriteInDB_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Тул киты, которые я находил, не подходят (или я не понимаю как им воспользоваться).

Comment: Надо учиться искать информацию самостоятельно или доки читать, ну или если это уже сделано, то хотя бы рассказать про это в вопросе

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ответ на ваш вопрос может быть где то здесь https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/textboxmask

Comment: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/MaskedTextBox